# puppeteer page.click(<selector>) but could not find it

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

This nodeJs uses Puppeteer to fill a multi page online website after login. One of the pages has an input image to click on but could not click on it using the codes below. Please indicate the reason why and how to correctly click on the input element.

```js
//server/main.js

  let submitLink = await page.$('input[src="/is/images/submitBtn.gif"]') //also tried  page.$('input[src=/is/images/submitBtn.gif]')
  await submitLink.click()
  
  Error:
   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
W20210606-15:29:14.995(10)? (STDERR)     at ElementHandle._clickablePoint
```

```html
 
<!-- here is the XPATH -->
<input type="image" name="action" src="/is/images/submitBtn.gif" value="submit" tabindex="7" title="submit" alt="submit">
```

Also tried `page.click(<selector>)` for no avail, here is the selector.

```js
body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td > form > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=image]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try this:

```js
  let submitLink = await page.$('input[src="/is/images/submitBtn.gif"]');
  await page.evaluate((submit) => { submit.click(); }, submitLink);
```

Sometimes `elementHandle.click()` fails due to more complicated emulation algorithm while simpler web API works.